# Alternatives to a homemade network KVM switch?

Tags: networking, kvm-switch, vnc

I'm wondering is there any alternatives to a network KVM switch? I'm looking to use one on my home machine while away. I'd be using it on 1 or 2 machines with Fedora / Windows XP/7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can set up linux to connect the console to the serial port (and I think there are ways to make this work with USB, but not sure), and many ups can be controlled from another computer, so if one is up, you can force a reboot.

VNC may also be what you are looking for.

What do you want to be able to do?

Comment: Would it be possible to access GRUB loader on start up over some form of KVM?

Comment: Yes, you can configure all of them to talk to a serial port, bios is the only hard part (either you can enable or you cannot, usually only server hardware). You can buy cards that will put the bios out over a serial port.

Years ago, at a dot com, I daisy chained a bunch of netra's so you could use one to talk to the next ones serial consol. Saved buying another terminal server (not good for prod though, when a machine goes down, there is a chance it will send a hardware suspend to the next machine, taking it down).

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with SSH and RDP; or VNC?

Answer (score -2):

Consider [Synergy2](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) and [quicksynergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/).

Though be sure to read the [security guide](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/security.html).

Comment: Synergy lets you share a single mouse/keyboard between multiple machines you are sitting in front of. It doesn't help for remote use, as the question is asking for.